# How can we assign new variables after each for loop iteration in python?

Tags: python, data-science-experience

Although it might be easy but i am not able to get a hang of it..

I want to assign the result to a new variable every time the for loop iteration occurs. I don't wish to do with initializing the list or dict and then adding the result. Because that way still it won't assign to a new variable each time.

Basically i want to automate this set of code.

```
data_Absen_1 = pd.read_excel('Absenteesim jan22.xlsx')
data_Absen_2 = pd.read_excel('Absenteesim feb22.xlsx')
data_Absen_3 = pd.read_excel('Absenteesim mar22.xlsx')
data_Absen_4 = pd.read_excel('Absenteesim apr22.xlsx')
data_Absen_5 = pd.read_excel('Absenteesim may22.xlsx')
data_Absen_6 = pd.read_excel('Absenteesim jun22.xlsx')
```

or you can consider automating this

```
data_Absen_1 = data[0]
data_Absen_2 = data[1]
data_Absen_3 = data[2]
data_Absen_4 = data[3]
```

Comment: because this line `data = data[i]` overwrites `data` variable on every iteration. you can do something like this `result = [] result.append(data[i])`

Comment: yeah, so how can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exec`

```
# let's create a list for testing purposes
data = list(range(100))

# to assign the 10 first values
for i in range(10):
    exec(f'data_Absen_{i+1} = data[{i}]')
```

Then you can directly access your variables

```
print(data_Absen_6)  # returns 5
```